# shortcut for equal weights to all elements in Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, shortcut, android-layout-weight

Is there any shortcut for making a LinearLayout that gives equal weight to all of its children?

I need to dynamically add views to a linear layout and I want to give equal weights to all of them. Is there any way to to this rather than programmatically add `layoutparams` to all of the children and then programmatically set the `weightSum` of the layout to be the number of elements inside the layout?

Comment: Um, just assign a `weight` of `1` to each child (in that child's `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`) and do not set `weightSum` on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: The weightSum is **optional**. Simply set all weights to **1**. Make sure the weighted dimension is set to **0dp**.

Comment: ohh i didn't know this:) thanks guys! i knew that there must be a short way for such a common task but never thought that the sum is optional...Please put an answer so i could upvote you and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that the weightSum is **OPTIONAL**, meaning that i could just set weight of all element to be 1 and never needed to touch the weightSum parameter.
thanks you guys for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For that you can give weightsum to linear layout and divide it into equal parts by giving layout_weight to all your views inside linear layout. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">
<View
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<View
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<View
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can try:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams loparams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)  v.getLayoutParams();

    // Set only target params:
    loparams.height = 0;
    loparams.weight = 1;
    v.setLayoutParams(loparams);
}
```